# Using a BitSet as a QueryParameter in a restful service

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

I naively created a restful handler that uses a `java.util.BitSet` as a `QueryParameter`.

```
@QueryParam("selectedCodes") BitSet selectedCodes
```

I suppose I shouldn't be surprised that I got the following error:

```
Unable to find a constructor that 
takes a String param or a valueOf() or fromString() method ...
```

I'd really like to represent the parameter as a `BitSet`. Is there any handy, dandy (what else is there?) piece of code that stringifys a `BitSet`?

Comment: Vote up for the answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement missing methods yourself. This should be trivial:

```
  class MyBitSet extends BitSet{

    public MyBitSet(String bits) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
          super(bits.length());
          for(int i = 0; i < bits.length(); i++){
            if(bits.charAt(i) > '1' || bits.charAt(i) < '0') {
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong bit!");
            }
            if(bits.charAt(i) == '1'){
               this.flip(bits.length() - 1 - i);
            }

          }
    }

  }
```

I haven't tested code, but it was easier for me to present the idea this way.

Answer (score 0):

`BitSet#toString()` produces a string of the form `{n, m, ...}` where the numbers are the indexes of one-bits in the set.

If that doesn't do what you want you'll have to write one, which should be pretty simple. You just have to define what "stringify a BitSet" means for your application.

There are several ways of tackling this but the issue boils down to one of deciding how to encode the bits.  You have several choices

- the default `toString()` works only for relatively short or very sparse long bit sets.
- a string consisting of '0' and '1' characters representing the set's values.  This is very low information density as you are taking up an entire byte to represent 8 bits.
- encode it in hexadecimal characters. This is more efficient (8 encoded bits represent 4 bits of data) but you might need to include the bit string length if it's not a multiple of 4 bits so you can reconstruct it correctly at the receiving end.

Your choice

Comment: Hi, thanks for this level of detail. I went with the 1's and 0's approach above because this seems to be a more language neutral solution. The default array wouldn't make a very good URI parameter and while the hexadecimal approach is efficient it may be too complicated all possible RESTful API users.